# AS3: call a static class method - class and method names are strings

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have an ugly problem. I have two string variables (className and staticMethod) store the name of a class and it's static method I have to call:

```
package {
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
 import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

 public class ClassPlay extends Sprite {

  public function ClassPlay() {
   new Foo();
   var className:String = 'Foo';
   var staticMethod:String = 'bar';
   var classClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(className) as Class;
   try {
    classClass[staticMethod]();
   } catch (e:Error) {}
  }
 }
}
```

This is the subject class:

```
package {
 public class Foo {
  public static function bar():void {trace('Foo.bar() was called.');}
 }
}
```

It works just perfectly. The problem when you comment out this (9th) line:

```
// new Foo();
```

Without this line it exits with an exception:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Foo is not defined.
```

How could I do this without that instantiation? If that is impossible, is there a way to instantiate the class from the string variable? Or if it's still a bad practice, how would you do that? (I have to work with those two unknown string variable.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that the compiler will strip out unnecessary classes - if you don't have an explicit reference to the class `Foo` somewhere, it won't be present in your final application.

You could the reference elsewhere and still force it to be loaded - for example, a static array of references to the classes.

Comment: This is also a common problem when using dependency injection in as3. For other options, check out http://www.springactionscript.org/docs/reference/html/Class-inclusion.html (note: the site is down now, but should be back eventually).

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you just throw in a trace(classClass) - that should give you the reference you need, if I remember this stuff correctly.

Comment: I don't think you even need to go that far. I belive if you just put the class name in your code (other than in a import statement) it'll get included. The complier is pretty dumb. for example:

Sprite;
MyClass;

Comment: No, it's not working. Error was thrown when classClass was initializing.