# Invoke static method using Introspection in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, static, introspection, method-invocation

All,

While this is similar to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045548/as3-call-a-static-class-method-class-and-method-names-are-strings), that post (does not indicate how to perform this (if it can be done) without instantiating an object.  Also, without success I have tried multiple variations on the theme of:

```
class[method](arg)
class[method].call(arg)
method.apply(class, arg)
```

I am new to Flex, but have used Reflection in both C# and Java.  BTW, the code that I am attempting to get to work in Flex is mirrored in both those languages and works as expected.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks,
Todd

Non-functioning Flex Code:

```
    private function ipMethodTester( ipMethodName:String,
             shouldPass:Array, shouldFail:Array):void
    {
        var message:String;
        var entry:String;
        for each(entry in shouldPass)
        {
            message = ipMethodName + ": " + entry + " should pass";
            try
            {
                Assert.assertTrue(message,
                    FieldValidator[ipMethodName](entry));
            }
            catch(e:Error)
            {
               Assert.fail(e.message + " " + message);
            }
        }
        for each(entry in shouldFail)
        {
            message = ipMethodName + ": " + entry + " should fail";
            try
            {
                Assert.assertFalse(message,
                    FieldValidator[ipMethodName](entry));
            }
            catch(e:Error)
            {
               Assert.fail(e.message + " " + message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Java Code:

```
private void ipMethodTester(final String ipMethodName,
         final String[] shouldPass, final String[] shouldFail)
{
   Method method;
   try
   {
      method = InetUtil.class.getDeclaredMethod(ipMethodName, String.class);
      method.setAccessible(true);

      for(String entry : shouldPass)
      {
         Object[] invokeArgs = { entry };
         boolean passed = (Boolean)method.invoke(null, invokeArgs);

         assertTrue(ipMethodName + ": " + entry + " should pass", passed);
      }

      for(String entry : shouldFail)
      {
         Object[] invokeArgs = { entry };
         boolean passed = (Boolean)method.invoke(null, invokeArgs);

         assertFalse(ipMethodName + ": " + entry + " should fail", passed);
      }
  }
  catch (final Exception e)
  {
     fail(e.getClass().toString());
  }
}
```

C# code:

```
    private void ipMethodTester(string ipMethodName, string[] shouldPass, string[] shouldFail)
    {
        Type type = typeof (ValidateUtil);
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.InvokeMethod
            | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static;

        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(ipMethodName, bindingFlags);

        foreach(string entry in shouldPass)
        {
            object[] invokeArgs = { entry };
            bool passed = (bool)method.Invoke(null, invokeArgs);

            Assert.IsTrue(passed, ipMethodName + ": " + entry + " should pass");
        }

        foreach(string entry in shouldFail)
        {
            object[] invokeArgs = { entry };
            bool passed = (bool)method.Invoke(null, invokeArgs);

            Assert.IsFalse(passed, ipMethodName + ": " + entry + " should fail");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the other post?  What code works fine in C#/Java?  You can call Static Methods in Flex using ClassName.MethodName .  I never tried to do that with a dynamic method name, though; I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: Requested information provided in update to question.

Comment: The try-catch within the loops of the Flex code is there for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
MyClass['myMethod']('arg1','arg2');
```

This also works:

```
MyClass['myMethod'].call(MyClass, 'arg1', 'arg2');
```

Note: the first argument of the 'call' method (MyClass in this case) just specifies which object is referenced when you use the 'this' keyword inside the function.

Comment: Dane, are the words in ticks considered strings?

Comment: I am getting "Error 1034 Type Coercion failed" with both of those.  I have checked and my arg type matches the arg type of the static method.  I don't know where else the coercion could be coming from.

Comment: Dane, added the non-functioning flex code to the original question.

Comment: Hmm, that looks fine to me. I think the problem must be occurring somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Dane, I need more clarification on the args.  Are all values passed required to be strings or are you indicating that myMethod takes string arguments?

Comment: The latter. Arguments can be any type, but in my example I used strings.

Comment: Dane, thanks for all your help and patience.  Apparently, my static block initialization is the root of the errors.